# How to change the font color of month and year picker in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the month and year list picker in jquery datepicker. The result of my datepicker is like this

[image]

As you can see, the month and year list font is shown white/blank, I can only saw the month name and year only when I select them.

[image]

I've tried to change the color in css file but, it doesn't change anything.

```
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
    width: 49%;
    color:black;
}
```

So, anyone here could help me to solve how to change the font color of my datepicker?

Comment: does `color:black !important;` help?

Comment: @DacreDenny Nope, nothing happened

Comment: all css in datepicker is based on element class (example .ui-state-default).
1. approach to access it via wrapper ID (#your-wrapper .ui-state-default). 
2. add "!important"

Comment: try select,option { color:black !important; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem : There is white color in month & year drop down list in jQuery UI `datepicker`

> Solution :
>
> - jQuery UI's default `color` is `#333` for Year & Month drop down, so here it is 100% change, that some other class is overwriting that default `color`
> - You need to change `.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month` and `.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year` color to as per your
>     requirement like `color:#000!important;`
> - Make sure this newly written class must applied only after jQuery UI css file imported.
> - Use developer toolbar to verify that new css is applying or overwriting by something else.

Check below example, Year and Month's drop down color is changed by red using css only:

```js
  $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
```

```css
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
    color:red!important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <P>Click on the textbox, see that Month & Year drop down color is changed!</p>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really help me to understand. This is work, actually just like @Dacre Denny said, but I'm mistaken some coding before, so at first time nothing happened.